# Count triple repetitions in a row

Tags: python

How can I implement a function in python to count triple repetitions in a row?

Example: given the string '111111aaaa', the function needs to return 3, by how many repetitions are 3 in a row (as `111-111-aaa-a`).

```py
def count_repeat(str: str) -> int:
    repeat = 0
    for i in range(len(str) - 2):
        if str[i] == str[i + 1] == str[i + 2]:
                repeat += 1
    return repeat
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the function that can fulfil your requirement:

```py
def count_repeat(s: str) -> int: 
    num = 0
    cur_rep = 1
    for i in range(1, len(s)): 
        if s[i] != s[i - 1]: # When the repetitions stops, add to answer and clear cur_rep
            num += cur_rep // 3
            cur_rep = 1
        else: # Length of current repetition plus one
            cur_rep += 1

    num += cur_rep // 3 # Remember to add last part

    return num
```

Iterate the string and handle it according to these two situation:

1. When current character is same as previous one, `cur_rep` plus one.
2. When current character is different from previous one, update answer and clear `cur_rep`.

`cur_rep` represents current length of string with same character.

PS:

1. I changed your previous variable name `str` to `s`. Because `str` is same as data type name in python, it may cause potential issues.
2. You can change `3` to other numbers to count other length of repitations.（Thanks to the comment of `anatolyg`）

Comment: This solution may be better than others because it's not limited to 3

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution using a `while` loop

```
def count_repeat(s: str):
    repeat: int = 0
    i : int = 0
    while i < len(s)-2:
        if s[i] == s[i+1] == s[i+2]:
            repeat += 1
            i += 3
        else:
            i += 1
    return repeat
```

A few notes:

1. I changed the parameter name from `str` to `s`.  Using an in use built-in name as a parameter/variable name can lead to problems.
2. As this is looking ahead 2 spaces, we can quit the loop 2 indexes before the end of the string.
3. Whenever we find a repetition, we can just jump the next index after the repetition

Comment: Bah, CtrlZ posted 54 seconds before me.  Wondering about the performance implications of that `set` conversion instead of just doing an index lookup though.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using `re` module:

```py
import re

s = "111111aaaa"

num_repetitions = sum(1 for _ in re.finditer(r"(.)\1{2}", s))
print(num_repetitions)
```

Prints:

```
3
```